# Dynamically allocate an array of dynamically allocated structures?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, malloc

I am trying to create a program to read a file and create an array of structures, filled with the data in the file. The problem is that when I run this I will sometimes get a 'debug assertion failed!' error expression: _CtrlsValidHeapPointer(block), sometimes there won't be a problem, and sometimes the Visual Studio debugger will say this:
Unhandled exception at 0x775C1B45 (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication6.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0040D510.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 256

struct Record {
char * firstName;
char * lastName;
char * address;
char * city;
char * state;
int * zipCode;
int * phoneNumber;
};

void initializeRecord(struct Record * list, char * lineOfText, int i);
void makeList(char * lineOfText, struct Record * list, int * psize);

int main(void) {
    char lineOfText[SIZE];
    int size = 0;
    int * psize = &size;
    struct Record * list = malloc(sizeof(struct Record));
    makeList(lineOfText, list, psize);
    free(list);
}

void makeList(char * lineOfText, struct Record * list, int * psize)
{
    FILE * fp = fopen("myfile.txt", "r");
    while (fgets(lineOfText, SIZE, fp)) {
        list = realloc(list, sizeof(struct Record) + (*psize)*sizeof(struct Record));
    initializeRecord(list, lineOfText, *psize);
    (*psize)++;
    }
fclose(fp);
}

void initializeRecord(struct Record * list, char * lineOfText, int i) {
char * newline = strchr(lineOfText, '\n');
if (newline)
    *newline = 0;

char * firstName = strtok(lineOfText, "\t");
list[i].firstName = malloc(strlen(firstName)+1);
strcpy(list[i].firstName, firstName);
list[i].firstName[strlen(firstName) + 1] = '\0';

char *lastName = strtok(NULL, "\t");
list[i].lastName = malloc(strlen(lastName)+1);
strcpy(list[i].lastName, lastName);
list[i].lastName[strlen(lastName) + 1] = '\0';

char *address = strtok(NULL, "\t");
list[i].address = malloc(strlen(address)+1);
strcpy(list[i].address, address);
list[i].address[strlen(address) + 1] = '\0';

char *city = strtok(NULL, "\t");
list[i].city = malloc(strlen(city)+1);
strcpy(list[i].city, city);
list[i].city[strlen(address) + 1] = '\0';

char *state = strtok(NULL, "\t");
list[i].state = malloc(strlen(state)+1);
strcpy(list[i].state, state);
list[i].state[strlen(address) + 1] = '\0';

int *zipCode = strtok(NULL, "\t");
list[i].zipCode = malloc(strlen(zipCode)*sizeof(int)+1);
strcpy(list[i].zipCode, zipCode);
list[i].zipCode[strlen(zipCode)] = '\0';

int *phoneNumber = strtok(NULL, "\t");
list[i].phoneNumber = malloc(strlen(phoneNumber)*sizeof(int)+1);
strcpy(list[i].phoneNumber, phoneNumber);
list[i].phoneNumber[strlen(phoneNumber)] = '\0';

}
```

Here is an example file (except that there shouldn't be entire new lines in between and there should be tabs between each element, I just can't see how to format it on StackOverflow):

Mary    Jones   6201 Wioewjife Ave  DOHfeo Hills    AZ  93321   2465551234

Billy   Bob 7290 DIowhoefh St   Uewopufeoi  NY  23311   2345552393

John    Jones   1234 EWOHFklfsh St  WEDhofehif  CA  98304   2345551238

Mark    Joe 2398 Yeiofejp Blvd  Hdeefoidjs  MT  13210   4355553973

My guess is that my problem is that when I allocate space for my array, I am not allocating enough space, as sizeof(struct Record) is probably not enough to store what I'm trying to copy, but I'm not sure how to create adequate space.

Comment: You allocated enough memory for the `'\0'` terminator, which is included by `strcpy`, but then with `list[i].firstName[strlen(firstName) + 1] = '\0';` unnecessarily write another terminator, beyond the array bounds.

Comment: Change API `void makeList(char * lineOfText, struct Record * list, int * psize);` to `void makeList(char * lineOfText, struct Record ** list, int * psize);`

Comment: Time to get friends with using your debugger. C programming cannot be done without being able to debug comfortably. As control flow is trivial here, focus on the data and I am sure you will see your problem(s) quickly.

Comment: @Weather Vane You're right. I fixed that a little bit after posting this, but I'm still getting errors. It was left over from when I was trying something else.

Comment: Also, don't use `strlen()` more than once per function unless the length of the string is changed during the execution of the function. Actually in your case, it's better to 1. Use `strdup()`. 2. If you are using an environment that has no `strdup()` or equivalent, write a simple `strdup()` function to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: @George please don't edit out mistakes in the code. Think about it - you'll end up with no question to answer, and readers will have no idea what the comments and answers were about.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest mistake in your code is assumption. You cannot assume things in a program and specially about data. When using `strtok()` you MUST check the return value for `NULL` which would indicate that there was no token found for the requested delimiter.

Using `strtok()` is also not the preferred way to tokenize a string because it's not a reentrant function, in simple situations that is ok but if it gets as complicated as parsing 2 strings, then it wont work.

When using `malloc()` always confirm that the allocation was successful. In a simple program it would not cause a big problem but in a data sensitive one you might destroy the important data. And that for many reasons, like losing a record because of a segmentation fault or writing corrupt data because dereferencing a `NULL` pointer does not guarantee a segmentation fault<sup>1</sup>. Which you should avoid. In a program that cannot be shut down line a web server, you MUST be sure that everything is checked for errors. So as a good habit **ALWAYS CHECK FOR ERRORS**.

Your code is also a good example of violating the [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), try cleaning it up so the mistakes happen in a single location then they will affect the program everywhere but you would have to fix them only at one place.

One more thing, since *`alloc()` functions return `NULL` on failure,

```
list = realloc(list, ...);
```

can be a problem, because you would overwrite `list` with `NULL` and lose access to the data it pointed too before the call to `realloc()`. Always use an auxiliary variable then `realloc()`, test for success and then overwrite the old pointer.

Even though it's very improbable that *`alloc()` functions fail, it's not impossible and a robust program should think that it can happen because it does.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It almost surely will happen, but according to the standard it should be *undefined behavior* so nothing guarantees a given behavior anyway</sub>

Comment: The OP indeed makes some unsafe assumptions, but I'd say the biggest mistake is the one @BLUEPIXY alluded to in his comment: `realloc()` is by no means certain to expand an allocation in-place.  In the event that it does not do so in the OP's `makeList()` function, the old pointer is invalidated, but the new pointer is not returned to the function's caller.

Answer (score -1):

You're telling `initializeRecord()` that you're sending a single Record, then you are trying to access it as an array of Records. This is what is causing you access violations.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean, specially after looking at the code.

Comment: First he creates a Record pointer. Which is correctly represented with "struct Record * list". Then it's being realloc so that "list" an array of "Record" pointers. But the array is still represented as a single pointer. Later the pointer to the first Record is passed to a method, and we're asked to access that pointer outside it's allocation be using it as an array.

Comment: And he passes the pointer and an integer to indicate which element to edit. It's correct.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble distinguishing between pointers and arrays.  It is *never* the case in the OP's code that `list` is regarded as an array of pointers, nor even a pointer to an array of pointers.  Rather, it is consistently treated as a pointer to the first element an array of `struct Record`.  Initially, it can be regarded is pointing at a one-element array; later, at a multi-element erray